# How to map a linear index to 2D index for array of list in python?

Tags: python, list

I was given a pile of linear indices for accessing an array of lists. Each list is of a different size. For example

```
data = [[1,2,3,4,5,6], # L1
        [2,3,4,5],  # L2
        [1,2,3],  # L3
        [7,9,10,11,18,22,1,3]]  # L4
```

Let me call the first list (on the top) L1, the second one L2, and so on. A linear index is given to pick up a view of the array composed of one element of each list at a time.

For example,

```
linear-index           view
0                      L1[0], L2[0], L3[0], L4[0]
1                      L1[0], L2[0], L3[0], L4[1]
2                      L1[0], L2[0], L3[0], L4[2]
3                      L1[0], L2[0], L3[0], L4[3]
k(k<len(L4)            L1[0], L2[0], L3[0], L4[k]
m=len(L4)              L1[0], L2[0], L3[1], L4[0]
m=len(L4)+3            L1[0], L2[0], L3[1], L4[3]
```

The linear index is moving along the very last list and towards the first list. I know that if the array is rectangular such that each list has the same length, I may use numpy's unravel_index to extract the 2d indices. To test it, I assume an array of 2 lists, each of length 3

```
data = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

there are a total of 9 linear indices, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 correspondings to the list of entries (values)

```
0 => [1,4]
1 => [1,5]
2 => [1,6]
3 => [2,4]
4 => [2,5]
5 => [2,6]
6 => [3,4]
7 => [3,5]
8 => [3,6]
```

I do not figure out a better way to do the mapping so I build the mapping by iterating all the data as

```
data = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]

idx2d = 0
idxmap = dict()
meters = [0]*len(data) # use to remember the pointer of the current position of each list
totalNumIndices = 1
for row in data:
    totalNumIndices *= len(row) # total number of linear indices could be

for idx2d in range(totalNumIndices):
    dd = []
    for n in range(0, len(data)):
        dd.append(data[n][meters[n]])
    idxmap[idx2d] = dd
    meters[len(data)-1] += 1
    for row in range(len(data)-2,-1,-1): # reverse the oder because the last list on the bottom will be access first
        if (meters[row+1] >= len(data[row+1])):
            meters[row] += 1
            meters[row+1] = 0
```

It seems to work. However, the actual data I was given is very large, and building such mapping in advance is not practical. I am looking for someone's advice for a better algorithm to compute the mapping with the given linear indices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, the following should work:

```
import itertools

data = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
dict(enumerate(itertools.product(*data)))
```

It gives:

```
{0: (1, 4),
 1: (1, 5),
 2: (1, 6),
 3: (2, 4),
 4: (2, 5),
 5: (2, 6),
 6: (3, 4),
 7: (3, 5),
 8: (3, 6)}
```

Since `enumerate(itertools.product(*data))` returns an iterator, it can build the mapping one element at a time rather than computing it all at once.